# Error using \tikzexternalize and different graphical inputs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, include, tikz-external

How can this issue be stated more precicely and finally solved?

Having a large document and using \input{...} within figure enviorement for including gaphics by tikz and pdf's, png's. Each figure itself works fine by commenting out any others. After a stepwise uncommenting of figures and always deleting the external-output folders content, the error occurs at an simple figure... \includefigure{pics/name.pdf}.

The folder structure is

- \folder\file.tex
- \folder\pics...pdf's,png's
- \folder\tikz...tikz's
- \folder\tikz\ext...pdf's,log's,dpth's

Commenting the \tikzexternalize lines in the preample, makes everything working fine, but - taking too much time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

By shrinking the code to an MWE, an unprocessed-floats error came up. Using a for-loop for multiple invoking of the same tikz, the error shows up after the 18th iteration (image). After including the morefloats package it was solved and successfully tested up to 30 images.